# Format a file based on the IFS

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I am using `sed` to concatenate the contents of a file as:

```
    cat source.c |  sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta'
```

The file contains relevant informations [ series of strings ] separated by a pipe `|`.
I want to change the `IFS` to a pipe `|`and get the output may be by piping to the new `IFS` thereby displaying the new formatted file to the stdout.

An instance of source.c after the concatenation :

```
    void f0 (***) | void f1 (***) | void f2 (***)| void f3 (***)
```

What I hope to achieve by setting the `IFS` :

```
    void f0 (***)
    void f1 (***)
    void f2 (***)
    void f3 (***)
```

Thanks in advance for the replies .I am not sure if it is possible with files , and I dont want to involve variables or arrays here .

EDIT : The source file appears some what like this in the beginning :

```
    void 
          f0 
         (***) |
    void 
               f1
                              (***) |
                   void                   f2                    (***) |
    void             f3                                                (***)
```

So first I concatenate then I double space each word group and then split using pipe as delimiter .

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta' source.c | sed -e 's/  */  /g' -e 's/ *//'
```

The `sed` and  `awk` alternative does the job perfectly .

Answer selected based on upvotes at the time of the first edit :) .
As suggested in one of the answers I am leaving the question unchanged in order for others to find these uncomplicated alternatives instead of messing with the `IFS`.

Comment: If the input to the `sed` is 'one function per line' and the required output from the process is 'one function per line', why are you going through the intermediate stage of 'flatten all functions in the file into a single line'?  Superficially, you seem to want your input format as the output format.

Comment: he's flattening on the original newlines and wants the pipe characters to replace them, so unless they're at the end or start of the line, the result will be significantly different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have edited the post to make it a little more clearer

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx  Exactly ! Thanks for covering  up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's exactly what you want, just replace '|' with newlines.

```
echo 'void f0 (***) | void f1 (***) | void f2 (***)| void f3 (***) ' | sed 's, *| *,\n,g'
```

Or with your command:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta' source.c | sed 's, *| *,\n,g'
```

Messing with the shell's IFS can get you very obscure problems. Messing with awk's is not a problem though:

```
echo 'void f0 (***) | void f1 (***) | void f2 (***)| void f3 (***) ' | awk 'BEGIN {RS="|";} { print $0}'
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta' source.c | awk 'BEGIN {RS="|";} { print $0}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat source.c | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="|" } {$1=$1; print $0}'
```

If you pipe the concatenated output to this `awk` script it will change pipe separators into newlines.

---

```
$ cat test
void f0 (***) | void f1 (***) | void f2 (***)| void f3 (***)

$ cat test | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="|" } {$1=$1; print $0}'
void f0 (***)
void f1 (***)
void f2 (***)
void f3 (***)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, awk only refreshes `$0` when a field is "modified", so if you touch `$1` then it trims extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_pipeline | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\| |\n";ORS="\n"}1'
```

The input record separator is a literal pipe followed by a space or a newline. The output record separator is a newline. The `1` is "true" which causes `$0` to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even bothering with sed/awk for this?  If I read the question correctly, you just want to remove all newlines and replace all `|` with a newline.

```
tr -d \\n | tr \| \\n
```

If your input file does not end in `|`, this will not print a terminating newline; in that case the overall command should be:

```
 < source.c tr -d \\n | tr \| \\n; echo
```